# How to make tests dependable on other tests result

Tags: javascript, typescript, selenium-webdriver, testing, automated-tests

I have a declared test pack in config file, that contains many tests files for example: homePage.ts, loginPage.ts ... and so on. Each of these tests uses a service and if that service is down there is no point in running test as it will fail. I want to check if service is up and I wanted to do it in a separate test file checkDependency.ts. While running test pack I want to first run checkDependency.ts and if it passes run all other tests in the pack, if it fails terminate everything.

I tried to export result of checkDependency.ts into another test file-  homePage.ts. When I want to check the imported result it is running the test scenario from checkDependency again.
How to do it so that checkDependency.ts runs only once and saves value of conditionPassed = true/false so that other test files can use it without running checkDependency again?

Comment: what framework are you using?